# Unwanted margin of <html> not set in CSS/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify

Testing my [Shopify store's](http://megagopher.com) responsiveness and found that at certain width some additional margin appears right-hand side of the entire `document`, but I can't find out why, 'cuz there's nothing at all related to margin/padding neither in CSS nor HTML itself.

I tried to supress scrollbars using `overflow-x: hidden` on `body` and `html` but it doesn't really help 'cuz on touch devices it's still possibele to scroll.

So far, I tested the issue on `Chrome v61.0.3163.100(Official Build)(64-bit)` and `Mozilla Firefox v47.0.1` in Developer Mode. It appears on width `832px` and `832px` correspondingly.

Also, tried to spy on how CSS's `@media`, `@query-at` stuff gets picked up in Chrome Dev Tools but still have no clue what causes this bloody inset.

Here's a screenshot of the issue.

[image]

Thanks for helping.

Comment: working fine on my system

Comment: Looks fairly obviously, the navbar is too long when I resize, just inspect it and you can see the insepctor points on items in the nav

Comment: Here's your culprit: `ul#moreMenu--list`

Comment: You are required to post your markup here. [mcve]

Comment: @Rob yeah I cognizant of that, unfortunately, it's not my css/html code but one which comes with Shopify template. And I'm not a frontend developer to identify which part of the whole theme.css could cause that. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update `left: 0` to `right: 0` for the dropdown in the More item

```
#moreMenu .site-nav--dropdown {
    right: 0;
}
```

Left 0 sets the menu item starting on the left side of containing parent and the with of it is longer than the parent length so it creates that extra space.

Comment: Have no clue how have you found it out, but it works for me. Just overrode `left: 0` to `auto` to let dropdown view be as wide as it wants. Thanks!

Comment: You just inspect that extra space and it's easy to see what's going on there

Comment: have tried that, but the whitespace I had there was to my eye imposed by the entire document. Probably, don't have enough practice with DevTools. Thanks a lot anyways.

Comment: You will get it with more use of it, you can also hover over elements in the inspect panel and there will be highlights on the page - this is also a great way to spot overflowing elements